# A Question about Assign Properties

Tags: iphone, properties, uitableview

**Edit 2:** What I previously planned was probably a bad idea and I now changed my design: My `UITableViewController` has an array with all the values of my `UITextField`s and I am using delegation to update the values in the array. (If a value in one `UITableViewCell` changes, I send a message with the new value and the index of the cell).

---

*Original Question*

I would like to create a `UITableViewCell` subclass. To access my cells, I would like to have an `NSMutableArray` in my `UITableViewController` with all the cells. Whenever I create a new cell in `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I would add it to the array. The cells should however know about this array. I would declare a property like this for the `UITableViewCell`:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray *cellsArray;
```

Whenever I create a new cell, I would set its `cellsArray` to my array.

My (probably simple) question is: Is it correct that `cellsArray` will hold a pointer to the array in the `UITableViewController` and when I add stuff to the array of the `UITableViewController`, the cells will know this too, i.e. can access it?

**Edit:** The `UITableViewCell`s contain `UITextField`s. I used to rely on the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and the `visibleCells` array, however when the cells moved out of view, the content of their `UITextFields` would also be lost. I then decided to store the cells in an array. When the user taps save, I iterate through the array and store the values. Also, I would like to automatically update the `enabled` property of the save button, depending on whether all cells contain something - for this I need all cells, too.

The cells should know about the other cells so that they can select the next cell when the return/next key on the keyboard is pressed.

If there are better approaches to this, I am glad to hear about them!

Comment: Why do you want a single cell to be able to access the entire array?

Comment: I'm wondering too why you'd want to do this. It seems you run a great risk of interfering with iOS's attempt to dequeue and reuse cells so references in your array may go stale it seems to me.

Comment: Why are you keeping an array of cells?  The table will keep them for you, and you can use the `reuseIdentifier` to differentiate among different cell types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a direct answer of your question, but this sounds like a very bad design. Why should one cell need to know about its siblings? Any event/change that occurs in one cell and has an effect on the other cells should be handled by the table view controller. The single cells should be separate entities that should have no need to know about the state of each other.

Secondly, there is no need to introduce another array to manage the table cells. The table view already has a property `visibleCells` that you can access from the table view controller. And should never have to interact with *invisible* cells anyway because those are managed by the table view and its reuse facility.

Comment: This wouldn't even work because the table view reuses the cells. So you are never able to store any data in your cells (and it is a violation of the MVC concept). You have to store the cell's data in the model as soon as the user changes it. The cell can be scrolled offscreen and reused the next moment. Your new design (Edit 2) sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is Yes.

My understanding of `assign` is that you can assign a value to such a variable and the retain count for the original object is not incremented. Similarly you need not release the variable in the object's `dealloc` method. You may run the risk, however, that the original array goes away and then `cellsArray` is pointing at something that is no longer there.

I use `assign` when I want to pass a reference to an object to another object (e.g. a view controller that is going to display or otherwise manipulate the object). And in the latter object, I do not release it's pointer to the object.

You also see `assign` used with properties that are `id`'s, like

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SomeProtocol> _myDelegate;
```

All that being said, with the exception of the `id` case, often I feel "safer" using `retain` for the property and being sure to release in `dealloc`. :-)

Anyway, I think that's the crux of the difference.